# How is it possible that the useEffect hook changes a state conditional on the change of the same state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useEffect hook which disables if title equals project.name:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (title === project.name) {
          setDisabled(false);
        } else {
          setDisabled(true);
        }
      }, [disabled]);
```

This works fine, but I do not understand how it works. From my understanding, the second argument of the useEffect hook specifies the variable that needs to be changed for the effect to take place. `disabled` is changed nowhere else in the code than in the effect itself.

From my logic, it would mean that disabled could never change, since the condition is prior to the effect.

Comment: "When `disabled` changes, run the effect"? The setting the state inside the effect will cause the effect to run again. Not sure why it doesn't cause a render loop?

Comment: That effect runs when `disabled` changes. Check with console.log statements or Chrome's React Debug tool to debug into this..

Comment: @evolutionxbox check out my answer please !

Comment: @evolutionxbox my pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

What is happening in your case, is that your application is **rendered twice** !

In fact, for every side effects (e.g., data fetching, manually changing the DOM, etc..), your application will be re-rendered, and this will call the hook (useEffect).

Effects are always executed after the render phase is completed even if you setState inside the one effect, another effect will read the updated state and take action on it only after the render phase.

The useEffect is similar to componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.

The setState (i.e., the setDisabled) will also **re-render** the application , so you will re-execute the useEffect hook.

**BUT**

*If you call the setState with is the same value as before, then the function component won't be re-rendered (the function component won't be called).*

Scenario:

1. at the first render, title !== project.name (supposing that), so we will enter into (title !== project.name) block code, and we will call the **setDisabled(true)**… This last call will re-render the application for a second time.
2. at the second render, now we have title === project.name, so we will enter into the (title === project.name) block code, and we will call the **setDisabled(false)** … This call will also re-render the application for one more time.
3. now, as we have title === project.name already set, so we will again enter into the block code of (title === project.name), we will recall the **setDisabled(false)**, but with the same value, so the application **will not be re-rendered again** !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to hear "title" if you want to change disabled, the second argument for the useEffect hook specifies the variable that needs to be hear for the effect take place.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (title === project.name) {
    setDisabled(false);
  } else {
    setDisabled(true);
  }
}, [title]);
```